# Solving equation-systems so it's understandable by an 11 year old

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to help my little brother with this math homework. The question:

*You have three numbers. The sum of these numbers are $7.2$. The second number is twice as large as the first one. The third number is three times as large as the first one.*

This is easily solveable by setting up an equation system such as:

$$a + b +c = 7.2$$
$$b = 2a$$
$$c = 3a$$

however, they haven't begun to touch these areas yet. Just trying out numbers and reasoning about it would feel fine if the sum was an integer, now, I have no idea how to help him solve it on his level.

Comment: If the numbers are $1$, $2$ and $3$, then the sum is $6$; since $7.2/6=1.2$, the three numbers are $1.2$, $2.4$ and $3.6$. False position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this approach:

> If the second number is *twice* as large as the first one, and the
>   third number is *three* times as large, then all three numbers
>   together are *six* times as large as the first one alone.

Knowing that all three numbers together also equal $7.2$, an attentive student's intuition should lead him to the solution without any formal arithmetic at all. In particular, it should be immediately apparent what the first number is.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the first number:

$$\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Here’s the second number:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
?&?\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And here’s the third number:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
?&?&?\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Adding them, we get

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
?&?&?&?&?&?\\ \hline
\end{array}\;,$$

which is plainly the same as

$$\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}\;,$$

just presented more efficiently.

So

$$\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}+\begin{array}{|c|}\hline
?\\ \hline
\end{array}=7.2\;,$$

and the first number must be one-sixth of $7.2$.

Comment: Yep. Do it with marbles or checkers or something. And 11 yr old will be able to grasp that, IMO.